# How to balance multiple message queues

Tags: algorithm, message-queue

I have a task that is potentially long running (hours). The task is performed by multiple workers (AWS ECS instances in my case) that read from a message queue (AWS SQS in my case). I have multiple users adding messages to the queue. The problem is that if Bob adds 5000 messages to the queue, enough to keep the workers busy for 3 days, then Alice comes along and wants to process 5 tasks, Alice will need to wait 3 days before any of Alice's tasks even start.

I would like to feed messages to the workers from Alice and Bob at an equal rate as soon as Alice submits tasks.

I have solved this problem in another context by creating multiple queues (subqueues) for each user (or even each batch a user submits) and alternating between all subqueues when a consumer asks for the next message.

This seems, at least in my world, to be a common problem, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of an established way of solving it.

I don't see any solution with ActiveMQ. I've looked a little at Kafka with it's ability to round-robin partitions in a topic, and that may work. Right now, I'm implementing something using Redis.

Comment: You didn't learn about [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)

Comment: @GuyCoder What would be helpful is if you could point me to some aspect of queueing theory that is applicable here. However, even though my problem involves queues, I don't think queueing theory is going to help since I know the behavior I want. I am simply trying to find a the best way of implementing the behavior.

Comment: There are 5003 messages, but only two actors. Serve the actors in round-robin, one message at the time (or one batch of messages, to speed it up a bit; you decide the batch size). This is what you actually wrote about, and it's a good approach.

Comment: Thanks @dialecticus for your analysis. I've committed a working implementation using Redis. Need more testing for how it will scale with many concurrent users, error conditions, etc, but good for a first stab at it. I funnel the actor queues into a singe ready-queue which I keep at a size no more than the number of active actor queues. The funneling logic uses a running status on which actor queues have been recently serviced the most.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) instead of queues as it supports long running operations and state management out of the box.

In your case I would create a workflow instance per user. Every new task would be sent to the user workflow via signal API. Then the workflow instance would queue up the received tasks and execute them one by one.

Here is a outline of the implementation:

```
public interface SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    @WorkflowMethod
    void execute();

    @SignalMethod
    void addTask(Task t);
}

public interface TaskProcessorActivity {
    @ActivityMethod
    void process(Task poll);
}

public class SerializedExecutionWorkflowImpl implements SerializedExecutionWorkflow {

    private final Queue<Task> taskQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final TaskProcesorActivity processor = Workflow.newActivityStub(TaskProcesorActivity.class);

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        while(!taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
            processor.process(taskQueue.poll());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTask(Task t) {
        taskQueue.add(t);
    }
}
```

And then the code that enqueues that task to the workflow through signal method:

```
private void addTask(WorkflowClient cadenceClient, Task task) {
    // Set workflowId to userId
    WorkflowOptions options = new WorkflowOptions.Builder().setWorkflowId(task.getUserId()).build();
    // Use workflow interface stub to start/signal workflow instance
    SerializedExecutionWorkflow workflow = cadenceClient.newWorkflowStub(SerializedExecutionWorkflow.class, options);
    BatchRequest request = cadenceClient.newSignalWithStartRequest();
    request.add(workflow::execute);
    request.add(workflow::addTask, task);
    cadenceClient.signalWithStart(request);
}
```

Cadence offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.

Comment: Thanks! Cadence Workflow might be a little too heavyweight for my immediate needs, and I would need to have buy-in from my organization as a whole, but very good to know about as an option.

Comment: Feel free to contact us if you want more info about it.